# Passing Several NSStrings to another view - Iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, nsstring, global-variables

In my iPhone app, the user will be making multiple NSStrings. Once these are made, I need to pass them to another view completely in the app. How can i do this? All I know at the moment os I can't access objects or variables declared in one view, in another. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to follow the [MVC (model view controller) design pattern](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html). Whichever controllers are responsible for your respective views can then store and retrieve the NSStrings from/to a common data model object.

As to how you can make the strings stored in an object visible to the outside, the easiest way is to use Objective-C properties to save you from writing the accessor methods yourself.

I hope this helps with your problem or at least gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Any chance of an example? Im not sure where to start, never worked with this before.

Answer (score 0):

Place the strings in a data model object (the M of the MVC pattern), with accessor methods (getter and setters, which can be automagicly created by properties).  Then create and place that model object in some central location, a controller common to all views requiring that data, or the appDelegate, a reference for which can be found from any view.

Comment: Any chance of an example? Im not sure where to start, never worked with this before.

Answer (score 0):

Josh,

I would add to the MVC thing, that still you can do this in several ways.

What I would do for example, is to make your other "View Controller" (MVC), to "[observe](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html)" when does the user create a new string, and to fetch it accordingly. In that way you would reduce coupling and it will be a cleaner implementation.

Another way would be to create a "[delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)" so that the First View controller, "notifies" or calls the delegate method that you created, each time the user creates a new string ( again reducing coupling )

Comment: Any chance of an example? Im not sure where to start, never worked with this before.